Spring boot: Define a custom method on domain model
I'm receiving a string coded location on feedLocation and I've defined a method to split the string in three coordinates x, y, z.
public class Feedback {
    @Column(name = "feedback_id")
    private @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="my_entity_seq_gen") Integer feedbackId;
    @Column(name = "feed_date", columnDefinition= "TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE DEFAULT clock_timestamp()")
    private LocalDateTime feedDate;
    @Column(name = "sens_code")
    private String sensCode;
    @Column(name = "feed_value")
    private Double feedValue;
    @Column(name = "location")
    private String feedLocation;
    @Transient
    private Double longitude = coordinates("x");
    @Transient
    private Double latitude = coordinates("y");
    @Transient
    private Double altitude = coordinates("z");

}

Coorrdinates method is getting the string coordinate which is still null and it's causing the compilation failing.
public Double coordinates(String coordinate){
            
        String wkbString = feedLocation;
        
        WKBReader reader = new WKBReader();
 
        Geometry geometry;
        
        try {
            geometry = reader.read(Hex.decodeHex(wkbString.toCharArray()));
        } catch (ParseException | DecoderException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
 
        String geometryText = geometry.toString();
     
        if (geometry.getGeometryType().equalsIgnoreCase("Point")) {
            
            double latitude = geometry.getCoordinate().y;
            double longitude = geometry.getCoordinate().x;
            double altitude = geometry.getCoordinate().z; 

            switch (coordinate) {
                case "x":
                    return longitude;
                case "y":
                    return latitude;
                case "z":
                    return altitude;                
            }
            
            return null;
        }

        return null;
    }

I expect to get the correct value on those three cordinates, but when I compile a get an error, because when the class get initialized feedLocation is still null.
Stack trace:
Exception in thread "restartedMain" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not get constructor for org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:740)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:415)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1312)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1301)
    at com.IOTProjectUI.Application.main(Application.java:26)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not get constructor for org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:421)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not get constructor for org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister
    at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:123)
    at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:77)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetamodelImpl.initialize(MetamodelImpl.java:181)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:319)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:471)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1498)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.InstantiationException: could not instantiate test object : com.IOTProjectUI.domain.Feedback
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.UnsavedValueFactory.instantiate(UnsavedValueFactory.java:43)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.UnsavedValueFactory.getUnsavedIdentifierValue(UnsavedValueFactory.java:68)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.PropertyFactory.buildIdentifierAttribute(PropertyFactory.java:65)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityMetamodel.<init>(EntityMetamodel.java:142)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.<init>(AbstractEntityPersister.java:613)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister.<init>(SingleTableEntityPersister.java:126)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
    at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:96)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.UnsavedValueFactory.instantiate(UnsavedValueFactory.java:40)
    ... 44 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "String.toCharArray()" because "wkbString" is null
    at com.IOTProjectUI.domain.Feedback.coordinates(Feedback.java:98)
    at com.IOTProjectUI.domain.Feedback.<init>(Feedback.java:66)
    ... 50 more


Show the exact error and stacktrace, the coordinates() method as well. I highly doubt you get a compilation error, seems more like a runtime error.

Please provide more information about your method, what is a trigger for method invocation, how class is initialized, what is "I'm receiving" - how you receiving it, is a field not empty in received message

Delay invoking coordinates() until you have the data in feedLocation. Either 1) Invoke it together with the setter for feedLocation, you can be sure you have already received the data. Or 2) Calculate the longitute, latitude, altitude in their respective getters, on demand, use the instance variable to cache the calculation result.

Define 3 getters, not fields, that delegate to said method. Fields won't work as then the value would need to be available upon construction of the class. The value is only available after the setFeedLocation has been called not before. Hence construction of the object will always fail.

@Chaosfire I've updated question with the method and the stack trace.

In order to fix your issue, you should move the calculation of the coordinates to the getter methods:
public class Feedback {
    @Column(name = "feedback_id")
    private @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="my_entity_seq_gen") Integer feedbackId;
    @Column(name = "feed_date", columnDefinition= "TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE DEFAULT clock_timestamp()")
    private LocalDateTime feedDate;
    @Column(name = "sens_code")
    private String sensCode;
    @Column(name = "feed_value")
    private Double feedValue;
    @Column(name = "location")
    private String feedLocation;

    public Double getLongitude() {
        return coordinates("x");
    }

    public Double getLatitude() {
        return coordinates("y");
    }

    public Double getAltitude() {
        return coordinates("z");
    }
}

That way, you will avoid calculating the fields during object initialization but they will be calculated when needed instead.
Keep in mind that the fields will be recalculated every time using this approach.
To avoid that you can use @PostLoad annotation instead:
public class Feedback {
    @Column(name = "feedback_id")
    private @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="my_entity_seq_gen") Integer feedbackId;
    @Column(name = "feed_date", columnDefinition= "TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE DEFAULT clock_timestamp()")
    private LocalDateTime feedDate;
    @Column(name = "sens_code")
    private String sensCode;
    @Column(name = "feed_value")
    private Double feedValue;
    @Column(name = "location")
    private String feedLocation;
    @Transient
    private Double longitude;
    @Transient
    private Double latitude;
    @Transient
    private Double altitude;

    @PostLoad
    private void postLoad() {
        this.longitude = coordinates("x");
        this.latitude = coordinates("y");
        this.altitude = coordinates("z");
    }
}

For more details, check out this excellent blog post: https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-map-calculated-properties-with-jpa-and-hibernate-formula-annotation/
